# why the initial-scale=1 in the viewport meta tag does nothing?

Tags: html, css, iphone, viewport

DO you know what may be the problem? After adding the code below in the header the viewport will fit to screen in chrome at 320px but will not fit to width on the iphone Safari (there seems to be a margin at the right). However on an Android device it displays correctly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works with `maximum-scale` and `user-scalable` attributes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```